# Обработка нажатия нескольких кнопок в форме

Tags: jquery, javascript, form

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать следующую идею.

Есть страница с таблицей. В каждом ряду есть пара кнопок, по нажатию на которые выполняются разные действия с полями. Например

```
имя   | телефон |  адрес   |действия
Антон | 1234    |  дом n5  |[Удалить][Переименовать][...]
```

Когда была одна кнопка сделал так

```
<form id="'.$row['id'].'" class="people">
    <input type="text" id="'. $row['id'] .'_name" value="'. $row['name'] .'">
    <input type="text" id="'. $row['id'] .'_tel" value="'. $row['tel'] .'">
    <input type="text" id="'. $row['id'] .'_address" value="'. $row['address'] .'">
    <button>Переименовать</button>
</form>
```

и обработка

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.people", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var id = form.attr("id");
    var name = $("#"+ id+ "_name").val();
    var tel = $("#"+ id+ "_tel").val();
    ....
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать под несколько разных кнопок? Проблема в том, что форм много и как по нажатию получить поля из родительской формы не понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай атрибуты data- для кнопок в которых укажешь action (что делать) и id ряда с которым сделать.
К примеру

```
<button data-id="7" data-action="rename">Переименовать</button>
```

При клике доставай все эти данные и вызывай нужный обработчик

```
var id = $(this).data('id')
var action = $(this).data('action'); 
if(action=="rename") {
    var tel = $("#"+ id+ "_tel").val(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам вообще делать submit формы? Вы же, как я понимаю, собираетесь передавать данные ajax-запросом. У каждой формы надцать кнопок со своими определенными классами, отслеживаете нажатие этих кнопок, в зависимости от класса то или иное действие. Можно не классы использовать, а какой-нибудь другой атрибут. Получится что-то вроде:

```
if(кнопка.hasClass('update')) {
   // апдейтим данные
}
```

Можно заранее подготовить объект с соответствующими функциями действий, а ключами в этом объекте могут так же служить какие-то атрибуты кнопок.